# Сравнение папок командой diff

Tags: linux

Есть две папки под svn: new и old. Я их сравниваю с помощью:

```
$ diff -r new old
```

Как сделать, чтобы diff пропускал папки .svn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

diff --exclude=".svn" -r new old

Comment: Именно то, что надо.